# jquery validate with ONE Error-Message for all formelements

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have a problem.
I must use the jquery validation function/plugin and i would like ONE error-Message for all formelements.

The errormessage would be display out of my form, at the top of my page.

Comment: could you please show us some code which you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - i have a solution for my problem.
I have write a new code base (the old code was to dirty) for this project and with the following code, i can use a default error handling.

```
   $('#FORMID').validate({

    errorContainer: container,
    meta: "validate",

    onfocusout: false,
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList){
        $('li.error').show();
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
...
```